# How do I see mail related errors in Django logs?

Tags: python, django, email

I'm trying to figure out why mail isn't being sent from a django application I copied from a perfectly working application where the mail works. I've tried in vain to get django to spit out something related to mail in the logs, but nothing shows up. Here are my settings in settings.py:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(module)s %(process)d %(thread)d %(message)s'
        },
        'simple': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        },
        'console': {
            'level':'DEBUG',
            'class':'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'simple'
        },
        'file': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': '/tmp/ooto.log',
            'formatter': 'verbose'
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'django_opensso':{
            'handlers' : ['file'],
            'level' : 'DEBUG',
        },
        'timekeeper':{
            'handlers' : ['file'],
            'level' : 'DEBUG',
        },
    }
```

Can someone explain in detail or post an example of how I can get mail related errors out of django so I can troubleshoot the real problem?

Comment: What application is the mail being sent from?  Is it `timekeeper`?  If so, is `timekeeper` in `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: Yes and yes on that one.

Comment: Does the `timekeeper` code contain logging messages?

Answer (score 0):

Neither `django.core.mail` nor `smtplib` are using Pythons logging module. There is a simple logging facility in `smtplib` that write to the console. You have to set run `.set_debuglevel(level)` on the connection instace, where level is an integer > 0.

This *should* have the same result:

```
import smtplib
smtplib.SMTP.debuglevel = 9
```

This is a so called monkey patch. Be careful with it, it is hard to trace.

Comment: Assuming the mail calls are wrapped in a try/except, and the logging is done in the except, then the logs are coming from _his_ code, not the mail module directly.

Comment: @JohnGordon Yeah, that would seem to be correct. I'm going to check that stuff today and inject my own logging if I have to! (It's not my code though, I'm working on someon else's application without being able to talk to them about it.) :D